# Why aren't the action listeners working

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

The `ActionListener`s are set up properly but for some reason are not working when I press one of the buttons. Any ideas? I have searched for ways to do it but nothing seems to work. Here is [my code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1p4awUtKzZ9vfbQ59FaFKlBbzIfzGK963nliXSraBp5Y/edit):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Master extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    final static String SIGNIN = "Sign In";
    final static String SIGNOUT = "Sign Out";
    final static String OTHER = "Other Stuff";
    final static int extraWindowWidth = 100;

    public String[] Names, SecurityNumber;
    public int FirstService = 0;
    public int SecondService = 0;
    public int counter = 0;

    protected JTextField ChildName, ChildSecurityNum, SecurityNum;
    protected JButton SignOut, FirstServiceButton, SecondServiceButton,
            FirstServiceTotal, SecondServiceTotal;

    public Master(Container pane) {
        // Set up Arrays for storage
        SecurityNumber = new String[300];
        Names = new String[300];

        // Text Fields
        ChildName = new JTextField("");
        ChildName.setEditable(false);
        ChildName.setColumns(10);

        SecurityNum = new JTextField("");
        SecurityNum.setEditable(true);
        SecurityNum.setColumns(2);

        ChildSecurityNum = new JTextField("");
        ChildSecurityNum.setEditable(true);
        ChildSecurityNum.setColumns(5);

        // Buttons
        SignOut = new JButton("Sign Out");
        SignOut.setActionCommand("signOut");
        SignOut.setEnabled(true);

        FirstServiceButton = new JButton("Sign In First Service");
        FirstServiceButton.setActionCommand("signinfirst");
        FirstServiceButton.setEnabled(true);

        SecondServiceButton = new JButton("Sign In Second Service");
        SecondServiceButton.setActionCommand("signinsecond");
        SecondServiceButton.setEnabled(true);

        FirstServiceTotal = new JButton("First Service Total Count");
        FirstServiceTotal.setActionCommand("firstservicetotal");
        FirstServiceTotal.setEnabled(true);

        SecondServiceTotal = new JButton("Second Service Total Count");
        SecondServiceTotal.setActionCommand("secondservicetotal");
        SecondServiceTotal.setEnabled(true);

        SecondServiceButton.addActionListener(this);
        FirstServiceButton.addActionListener(this);
        FirstServiceTotal.addActionListener(this);
        SecondServiceTotal.addActionListener(this);
        SignOut.addActionListener(this);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        // Create the "cards".
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel() {
            // Make the panel wider than it really needs, so
            // the window's wide enough for the tabs to stay
            // in one row.
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
                size.width += extraWindowWidth;
                return size;
            }
        };
        card1.add(new Label("Child's Name :"));
        card1.add(new JTextField("", 15));
        card1.add(new Label("Child's Security Number :"));
        card1.add(ChildSecurityNum);
        card1.add(new Label("Child's Grade :"));
        card1.add(new JTextField("", 2));
        card1.add(FirstServiceButton);
        card1.add(SecondServiceButton);

        JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
        card2.add(new Label("Enter Security tag # :"));
        card2.add(new JTextField("", 5));
        card2.add(SignOut);
        card2.add(new Label("Child's Name :"));
        card2.add(ChildName);

        JPanel card3 = new JPanel();
        card3.add(new JButton("Print Attendence Sheet"));
        card3.add(FirstServiceTotal);
        card3.add(SecondServiceTotal);

        tabbedPane.addTab(SIGNIN, card1);
        tabbedPane.addTab(SIGNOUT, card2);
        tabbedPane.addTab(OTHER, card3);

        pane.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("signOut".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            ChildName.setText("");
            SecurityNum.setText("");
            int counter = 0;
            for (String a : SecurityNumber) {
                if (a.equals(SecurityNum.getText())) {
                    ChildName.setText(Names[counter]);
                } else
                    counter++;
            }
        }
        if ("signinfirst".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            FirstService++;
            counter++;
            Names[counter] = ChildName.getText();
            SecurityNumber[counter] = SecurityNum.getText();
            ChildName.setText("");
            SecurityNum.setText("");
        }
        if ("signinsecond".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            SecondService++;
            counter++;
            Names[counter] = ChildName.getText();
            SecurityNumber[counter] = SecurityNum.getText();
            ChildName.setText("");
            SecurityNum.setText("");
        }
        if ("FirstServiceTotal".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + FirstService
                    + "Kids.");
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sign in and Sign out");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create and set up the content pane.
        Master demo = new Master(frame.getContentPane());
        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting an exception or just nothing happens when you click ?

Comment: nothing happens when i click on it. you can run the code yourself to see if it works for you.

Comment: Why do you think posting link to code is better than posting code itself?

Comment: *"The action listeners are set up properly but for some reason are not working"* would suggest your expectations and reality don't match, but without any runnable example which demonstrates your problem, it's impossible to know how you might fix it

Comment: the code is to long. it was making me have to right more about it.

Comment: "*the code is to long*" did you get rid of things which ware not related to the problem you are describing? Consider reading this article about how code examples should look like: http://sscce.org/

Comment: *the code is to long* surely not. I copy-pasted it into the question (edit awaiting approval). @Pshemo From what I have seen, he did not.

Comment: @Turing85 I suspect that you ware able to propose this edit containing entire code because of your reputation points. New users have less privileges like they can't post long code examples or images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any problem with your ActionListeners (determined through printing "hello world" upon the button being pressed). The problem is that you never added SecurityNum to card1, which is why its text isn't getting cleared.

Comment: place `System.out.println("hello world")` inside ` if ("signinfirst".equals(e.getActionCommand()))` and see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the buttons outside of the Master() constructor you may want to just do this for adding an action listener.

As an example:

```
signOut.addActionListener(this);
```

and this to get the action

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object o = e.getSource();
    if(o.equals(signOut)) {
        // Code to signout.
    }
}
```

You may also want to rename your variables so that that first character is lowercase (except for the final variables). It would make reading a bit easier.